# 'Reflecting' a Javascript Array - is this legal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found myself needing to convert from a small integer into a corresponding, arbitrary string. The obvious way to do this is with an Array. But I also wanted to go back the other way: given the string, find the corresponding integer. Obviously I could do this by Array.indexOf(), but handling the 'no match found' case was a bit awkward. But in Javascript, Arrays are Objects, and Objects have properties, so I tried defining a function:

```
var reflect = function(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[array[i]] = i;
    }
};
```

which adds a property corresponding to each array element. So given:

```
lighting2 = ['AC', 'HOMEEASY_EU', 'ANSLUT'];
reflect(lighting2);
```

I can write `lighting2[1]` giving me `'HOMEEASY_EU'`; and also `lighting2['HOMEEASY_EU']` which gives me `1`. Furthermore, `lighting2['FOO']` gives me `undefined` as it ought to. The `Array.length` property does not appear to be affected by this 'reflection'. The technique works - at least it works in node.js - but I have never seen it before. Is this 'legal'? Will it cause nasty things to happen? Is it likely to be useable in all Javascript implementations?

Cue the Javascript language lawyers!

Comment: `Array.indexOf()` returns -1 if it's not found, how is that "awkward"?

Comment: Sure, this is okay – if you need it and it makes sense from a design perspective. Typescript uses this technique for enums, to give you a serious example.

Comment: This brings undesirable (and unpredicatable) behaviour when you add new members to the array, and forget to run "reflect()" again (as *some* elements will have been reflected, but others won't have been). You also have problems that duplicate elements can only map to a single index. So, whilst *legal*, I wouldn't say it had a clean API.

Comment: @Matt I would rather say that adding new values later on is dirty usage of the principle. If you consider such objects immutable, then I don't really see anything wrong with it. As I said above, Typescript has a pretty good use for this.

Comment: @IngoBürk: But it's not dirty usage of an array, it's very much what they were designed for. What the OP is doing however, *is* dirty use of an array. One broken consumer of this API can break it for everyone. Instead, the API should expose `add(item)`, `getElementAt(index)` and `getIndexOf(item)` methods. This should be implemented by an object which exposes only those methods, and which (potentially) uses this array reflecting concept internally.

Comment: @IngoBürk: I should have said this trick is done only one time;  these arrays are effectively constants defined when the program is loaded and then used read-only. @Matt: I like that technique - in fact I don't need the `add(item)` method as I can pass always pass the array of strings to the constructor function.

Comment: A bit of Googling turns up several implementations of a 'BiMap' class, which does what I am doing in a more general & robust fashion: e.g. https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html and http://tomjefferys.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/bimaps.html